# changes in package from drools version 5.2.0 to drools version 6.2.0

Tags: drools

My project uses drools 5.2.0, we are trying to upgrade to 6.2.0 but we are facing problems with package structure and class not found.
The class which we are facing problem are mentioned below :

```
org.drools.core.Package
org.drools.RuleBase
org.drools.RuleBaseFactory
org.drools.compiler.PackageBuilder
```

Please let me know how to resolve above errors.

Comment: The classes you've mentioned are not part of the stable API of 5.3.0, and I don't think they were in 5.2.0. There was always a warning against using such classes. You may have to look for ways to replace the code using whatever is available with 6.2.0, but there's no guarantee that this is easy.

Comment: I tried using method of KnowledgeBuilder,kBuilder.add(ResourceFactory.newUrlResource( ruleSourceStream ), ResourceType.DTABLE); but it is throwing an exception of 'path is malformed'.

Comment: Ask another question, providing more of the code and the stack dump.